# SQL query to combine two user tables, remove duplcates and find the latest update entry for each user

Tags: sql, inner-join, user-defined-functions

I have two SQL tables. TableA has a list of active users, TableB has a list of all help tickets the users submitted with emails and submit dates.

I need to output a list of users that exist in Table A & Table B (excluding users only in TableB) along with the date of the last help ticket they submitted. This is because several users were removed from the active users table, but their help tickets remain in the second table.

Table Fields:

```
eUser
eUserName, eEmailAddress

Work_Orders
txtContactEmail, SubmitDate


Desired output:
eUserName, eEmailAddress, SubmitDate
```

**My Attempt**

```
SELECT   eUser.eUserName
       , eUser.eEMailAddress
       , Work_Orders.txtContactEmail
       , max(Work_Orders.dtRequest) lastupdate 
FROM eUser inner join Work_Orders 
on eUser.eEMailAddress = Work_Orders.txtContactEmail 
group by eUser.eUserName
       , eUser.eEMailAddress
       , Work_Orders.txtContactEmail
```

Comment: @M.Ali, thanks for your help formatting, I still haven't gotten the hang of it it seems. Thanks!

Comment: It took me sometime to understand how it works. Once you have added the text, select the text and click on `[]` in the formatting tab. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  A.eUserName,
        A.eEmailAddress,
        B.MaxSubmitDate
FROM TableA AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT txtContactEmail, MAX(SubmitDate) MaxSubmitDate
            FROM TableB
            GROUP BY txtContactEmail) AS B
    ON A.eEmailAddress = B.txtContactEmail
```

Comment: This query runs, however, it returns the users that exist in Table A and Table B. I need to exclude the users that exist only in Table B.

Comment: @GrimPython I don't understand your comment.

Comment: TableA is a list of active users. TableB is a list of help tickets. Many users were deleted from TableA, but their help tickets were not deleted from Table B. I don't want to see users from Table B that were deleted from TableA.

Comment: @GrimPython And they won't show since it's an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Table A has 445 users listed. Table B has 100K records. Using your query I get 460 results. As this is more results than users in TableA I assume some users are being drawn from TableB. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Yes, it's incorrect. What is probably happening is that you have multiple users in table A that have the same email address, hence duplicating some of your results.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. I marked your answer as a correct one!